# If property exists logic in BizTalk message assignment shape

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is the `if / else` logic valid in a BizTalk Message Assignment shape?

I'm getting some event log errors regarding ErrorReport.FailedTime having no value, so I thought I'd put a guard clause in the

```
if (ErrorReport.FailureTime exists Msg_Failed)
{
    Var_FailureTime = Msg_Failed(ErrorReport.FailureTime);
}
else
{
    Var_FailureTime = System.DateTime.Now;
}
... rest of code constructing the error report message ...
```

But the compiler fails with ...

```
error X2254: unexpected keyword: 'if'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior.

'If' is not supported in the Message Assignment Shape but it is supported in the Expression Shape.  so, you will have to do this test/assigment before the Construct Shape.